# Pass parameter in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Rails 3.2. Here, I wanna direct all `http://domain.dev/toys` to only show all `shops` which `shop_type` (in my table column) is `toys`.

```
# routes.rb
resources :shops

match 'toys' => 'shops#index', :as => :toys, :via => :get, :constraints => {:shop_type => 'toys'}

# shops_controller.rb
def index
  @shops = Shop.find(:all)
end
```

What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The wrong part: `Shop.find(:all)`.

[Constraints are for route segments.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints)

(Well, and verbs, but then they're specified with `:via`; or methods on `Request`.)

Comment: Mind to share some ideas how to improve it?

Comment: @Victor You need to do a find with the appropriate shop type--not sure what the cleanest way to do it is, but the easiest is to just create a method that does so, call it, and render the appropriate template.

Answer (score 0):

In `routes.rb`:

```
match 'shops(/:shop_type)' => 'shops#index', :via => :get, :as => :shops_path
```

In `shops_controller.rb`:

```
SHOP_TYPES = [:toys, :clothing, :accessories]

def index
    @shops = []
    if SHOP_TYPES.include? params[:shop_type].to_sym
        @shops = Shop.find_all_by_shop_type(params[:shop_type])
    else
        @shops = Shop.find(:all)
    end
end
```